# Joining three tables using result from one SQL query on one of the tables

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, subquery

I'm trying to search one table for entities with a certain field in one table and use fields within that entity to to join it with two other tables specific fields
[first I search for entities with CustomerID == 2 and use their other fields to search to other tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tae5j.png)
[Using BoxTypeID from those specific entities I want to find the corresponding BoxType](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RLuf.png)
[Using WarehouseID from those specific entities I want to find the corresponding name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZkf5.png)

Once I have found all three fields (BoxID, BoxType, name) I want to display them all in one table

I have some SQL that works but only displays the BoxID and Warehouses.name. I can get it to also display BoxID and BoxType however not all three at once.

```
SELECT Boxes.BoxID, Warehouses.name AS Warehouse
FROM Boxes
INNER JOIN Warehouses
ON Boxes.WarehouseID = Warehouses.WarehouseID
WHERE Boxes.CustomerID = 2;
```

[resulting table from query above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyh2E.png)

However once I try to apply another JOIN it doesn't work

```
SELECT Boxes.BoxID, Warehouses.name AS Warehouse, BoxTypes.BoxType as Size
FROM Boxes
INNER JOIN Warehouses
ON Boxes.WarehouseID = Warehouses.WarehouseID
INNER JOIN BoxTypes
On Boxes.BoxTypeID = BoxTypes.BoxTypeID
Where Boxes.CustomerID = 2;
```

Comment: Please remove any links and images and then show sample input and expected outcome as tables.

Comment: Only one WHERE clause is allowed in a  query. Drop one in the middle of the query.

Comment: Add tag for RDBMS used.